# Can I remove Windows 10 Timeline's nudge to "see more days in timeline"

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, task-view, timeline

For users who haven't signed in with a Microsoft account and given Microsoft access to their computer activity, the Windows 10 task view contains a message right below the currently open applications:

[image: Notably missing: a button for "No, don't ask me again"]

Naturally, because this is Windows 10, there's no way to dismiss this nudge except by giving up and letting Microsoft harvest your computer activity for fun and profit. This irritates me *immensely*.

My question is, can any of you lovely individuals help me make this go away? Is there a registry edit I can make? It's hard to just avoid task view, as I have a 2-in-1 laptop and task view is the easiest way to switch windows in tablet mode, as well as the only way I know to manage multiple desktops.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out also, and haven't been able to so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following on lincb's answer, you can set the registry key corresponding to that group policy at:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System]
"UploadUserActivities"=dword:00000000
```

That is, at that path in the registry, add the 32-bit DWORD

`UploadUserActivities`

and set its value to 0.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I am not able to check either, but it's worth a shot. For what it's worth, it seems like it will work since it's been covered on some websites.

Comment: This registry key works for me on Windows 10 Home (1909).

Answer (score 23):

On Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, or Education, you can use Group Policy to disable the option to upload activity, and this seems to dismiss the nudge. Here are the steps:

- Click **Start**, search for **gpedit**, and click the top result **Group Policy Editor**
- Browse to the path `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\OS Policies`
- Double-click the **Allow upload of User Activities** policy
- In the pop-up window, select the **Disabled** option, then click **Apply** and **OK**

The nudge in Task View should then no longer appear.

I found this as part of the instructions in https://pureinfotech.com/disable-timeline-windows-10/.

Comment: Seems like this is on the right track. Is there any way for me to do this given that I have none of those versions? I just have the bog-standard Windows 10 that came with my new laptop.

Comment: @Empiromancer - This simply modifies the UploadUserActivities key.  The author confirmed the registry key applied to Windows Home.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care to have the Timeline at all, you can disable this message and the timeline together by unchecking `Store my activity history on this device` in the `Activity History` settings. (Search for `Activity history privacy settings` in the start menu)